# Diameter of Cayley graphs whose generators intersect all large cosets

Tags: graph-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let $G = G_n= \Bbb{F}_2^n$. We say $A\subset G$ is *$t$-blocking*, if it has non-empty intersection with all cosets $C\subset G$ with codimension at most $t$.

Given a group $G$ and set $A\subset G$, we write $\Gamma(G,A)$ to denote the Cayley graph generated by $A$.

Given $n,t$, let $D(n,t)$ be the maximum diameter of a Cayley graph $\Gamma(G_n,A)$ where $A$ is $t$-blocking.

For all $n\ge 1$, we have that $D(n,1)\le n$, since if $A\subset G_n$ is $1$-blocking, it contains a basis, and thus $\Gamma(G_n,A)$ contains the $n$-dimensional hypercube as a spanning subgraph.

I'm wondering if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $t,N$ such that $D(n,t)<\epsilon n$ for all $n>N$. I should mention that I don't have a proof that $D(n,1)\gg n$.